# Why does the first term in the integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f'(x)e^{-i \omega x}dx$ vanish?

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals, fourier-transform

Given $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})\cap C^1(\mathbb{R})$, I'm trying to solve the following integral using integration by parts:

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f'(x)e^{-i \omega x}dx$$

I know that the final result should be the second term in the integration by parts (below), but I cannot see why the first part vanishes (note, I may be a little rusty on improper integrals).

Here's what I've done:

$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty f'(x)e^{-i \omega x}dx = \lim_{a \to \infty} \bigg(e^{-i\omega x }f(x) \bigg|_{-a}^{a} \bigg ) +i\omega \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-i\omega x} f(x) dx$$

Why is the first term $0$ (it definitely has to be because this integral is a known identity for Fourier Transforms)? What am I doing wrong / not seeing? When I plug in the limits, nothing seems to vanish (I used Euler's identity to transition to $sin,cos$ and I'm just not seeing it).

Thanks!

Comment: @user I thought of proving that, but I cannot see why it would be true. It cannot be a result of the function being in $L^1$ because there are continuous functions in $L^1$ that don't vanish at infinity.

Comment: @Anon There is a difference between [$L^1(\mathbb{R})$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#Lp_spaces_and_Lebesgue_integrals) and [$L^1_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb{R})$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_integrable_function). For $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})\cap C^1(\mathbb{R})$ user 's comment, that $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow \pm\infty}f(x)=0$ is true, while your observation is correct, that this no longer needs to hold for $f\in L^1_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb{R})\cap C^1(\mathbb{R})$. Maybe you can figure it out now and write down the answer yourself.

Comment: $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R}) \cap C^1(\mathbb{R})$ is not enough, but I suspect that the OP assumes $f' \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ instead, which is indeed sufficient by Sobolev embedding. Otherwise OP has some explaining to do what $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f'(x)e^{-i\omega x} dx$ even means...

Comment: This is continuous and integrable doesn't go to zero at infinity
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
2^{n+2} (x-n)  & \in [n, n+\frac{1}{2^{n+2}}]; n \in \mathbb N \\
2-2^{n+2} (x-n) & \in [n+\frac{1}{2^{n+2}},n+\frac{2}{2^{n+2}} ]; n \in \mathbb N \\
0, & \text{elsewhere} \end{cases}
$$
...but not differentiable

Comment: @Physor You can easily make this differentiable by considering something smooth instead of hats.

Comment: But that means that what the OP is trying to show is wrong, or I misunderstood something

Comment: @Physor Indeed, which is why I am suspecting that an assumption is missing; see my earlier comment.

Comment: @Klaus - Yes - it seems that in the notes I that have, the assumption $f' \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ is missing, but I found other notes that do include it. Since it's a known result in Fourier Transforms, it must be a mistake in the notes I've been using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, $f\in L^1\cap C^\infty$ does not imply that $f$ vanishes at infinity. But

> > **Lemma** If $f\in L^1(\Bbb R)$ then there exists a sequence $(a_n)$ with $a_n\to\infty$ and $|f(a_n)|+|f(-a_n)|\to0$.

That's enough to do the integration by parts, which is enough to show that $\lim_{a\to\infty}\int_{-a}^af'(t)e^{i\omega t}$ is what it should be (for $f\in L^1\cap C^1$)...

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, you're basically saying that instead of some general $a$ in the integral's boundaries, we can choose them to be $a_n$ and take $n \to \infty$? (I'm trying to see this formally).